# Copy to corresponding folder

Tags: regex, macos, bash

I'm trying to copy files from one set of folders to another where both sets of folders have the same structure. In microcosm, it resembles the following hierarchy:

```
source
 A1
  file
 A2
  file
 B1
  file

target
 A1
  file2
 A2
  file2
 B1
  file2
```

I want to copy all the files from `source` to their corresponding folders in `target`, without destroying the current content.

Comment: `cp -R` should do the trick.

Comment: Also just use `tree` to show your structure (whether you make a sample one or want to use your actual files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
cp -R <source> <dest>
```

Comment: ... I was all fired up to do some heavy-duty regex stuff, and now I just feel silly.

Comment: If I have other content in my destination, will `cp -R source/*/file destination` overwrite it?

Comment: @rsegal Yes.  use the `-u` flag to only copy if the source file is newer.

Comment: It won't overwrite them without the `-f` flag unless you tell it to overwrite them.